# Keep two remotes in sync

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket

I have a fun situation where I'm working with people at a different institution.  Both of us have firewall requirements that we have to meet.  We each have our own git servers.  To make working on the same repository as seamless on both sides as possible, we each use our own server with a copy of the same repository.  We have found that it is difficult to keep the repositories in sync with one another and that we are consistently needing to do extra work to avoid messy conflicts.

Is there a good way to keep our two repositories in sync automatically?  I've thought of putting together a pre-receive hook that checks the other server for changes prior to checking for conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding messy conflicts *is* one of the principles on which git was designed.

Most messy conflicts resolved in a git workflow would be a nightmare without a good VCS tool, to start with. Could it be that something in the way you're using git makes the process inconvenient?

If everyone commits often, and pulls remote changes to integrate often as well, you don't have that much messy conflicts in principle. What in your context makes it specially worse or unmanageable?

If there are compelling reasons to use another type of tool, a centralized one like SVN or P4, yes it's worth considering the switch. But be sure to have questionned your usage of git first, it could save a lot of trouble.

Comment: The problem we have is that commits don't get pushed from one remote to the other often enough.  Extra steps are required to keep the two repos in sync and since it is a manual process that is not required for repos that are only located on a single remote, users tend to forget the extra steps.  What I would like is this: When changes are pushed to remote A, remote A should first fetch from remote B, then check the push for conflicts prior to accepting the push.  This would make it so that conflicts are caught as early and as often as possible without requiring users to remember extra steps.

Comment: @Vorticity It seems to me that you're trying to replicate the characteristics of a centralized VCS with a decentralized one. But I'll let more experienced users confirm.

Comment: I think you're probably correct there.  It's kind of a frustrating setup we have.  Thanks for the comments!